# If statement not registering "save" rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up basic authentification/login for my app and have run into an annoying albeit minor issue.

Below is my "create" method:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end

    render "index"
end
```

Upon rendering index I will sometimes get form is invalid and sometimes you have signed up successfully, I will get form is invalid even when the data is successfully added to the db.

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
<div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
```

Comment: Is this action being called multiple times with the same parameters?

Comment: no, however I did notice I was missing def index. Could that be a factor?

Comment: Yes rails 4 requires you to have action definition, even if it is empty. Just add a `def index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you used `render` instead of `redirect_to`.

`flash` is something stored in session which will only take effect on next request.

In your controller, there is only one request, the flash is still some old info stored in session and `render` won't update it.

To fix, replace `render` with `redirect_to`

Comment: Working now in that when the form is invalid the data is not entered into the db. How can I find out why a form may not have saved?

Comment: you can redirect to index if success, and `render 'new'` if failed to show the form again with errors added.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things.

First look how `flash` works. If you put something it will stay there until the next request finished.

```
flash[:foo] = 'bar'
flash[:foo] #=> 'bar' 

# redirect the user or reload of the page
flash[:foo] #=> 'bar' 

# redirect the user or reload of the page
flash[:foo] #=> nil
```

For error messages that should be show within the same request, but not in the next, call `now`

```
flash.now[:foo] = 'bar'
flash[:foo] #=> 'bar' 

# redirect the user or reload of the page
flash[:foo] #=> nil
```

Further reading: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Another thing: If you not just handle a get request for data (but a create, update, delete instead), please redirect the users after that operation was successful. Not just render another view. The reason is that if the user reloads the page, the browser will resent its last request. And - in your case - try to create a second user with the same data.

tldr: If the `save` was not successful, `render` the form again. If the `save` was successful, `redirect` to user to `show` or `index`